# What was this exchange 花粥 had with the crowd?

Tags: listening, transcription

At the end of [this live performance of 远在北方孤独的鬼](https://music.163.com/#/song?id=1433736560) (at roughly 3:28 in the recording), some of the fans yelled “花粥带我回家” if I heard correctly. I'm trying to understand her response but she uses some words I'm unfamiliar with and I can't quite make out the pinyin.

To me her response sounds like ”你们这个tányàn'gǎode我，我现在有一点téngzhàng了” I'm not sure what tányàn'gǎode is. My computer suggests 坦言搞得, which is unfamiliar to me, though Google translates it as "frankly" which makes sense in context but then I don't really understand what's going on grammatically. Téngzhàng I have no clue. What did Hua Zhou say in this clip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her response should be "你们这个排面搞得我，我现在有一点膨胀了。“

"排面"（pái miàn) can be roughly translated to "grandeur" or "flamboyance", but there is a subtle difference between the Chinese word and these two translations. Let me try to give an example where the word 排面 can be used quite naturally in Chinese:

A young entrepreneur in a middle-sized city in China had established a small company, and he arranged a dinner party to celebrate the anniversary of its establishment. He is still not very rich but wanted to showcase the financial capacity of his company, so he arranged the dinner party in the banquet hall of a five-star hotel and ordered it to be decorated with flamboyant ornaments, and invited an orchestra band to play music throughout the party. He even invited quite a few notable officials in the municipal government to attend the party. In this case, it would be very natural for an attendee of the dinner party to comment "这聚会真有排面啊”. However, if the entrepreneur is of the conceited and ambitious type of people, he may feel a little unhappy when hearing someone commenting as such in public, because 排面 is usually not applied to members of the upper-class society or to those genuinely rich people (unlike "grandeur", which often implies being rich), but rather to those who are showcasing a little bit beyond their financial capacity.

However, on the other hand, 排面 can also simply refer to things that seem a little unnecessarily well-arranged. For example, when a young worker born in a relatively poor family in rural China returns to his home during the Spring Festival, and saw that his mom prepared six different dishes for dinner to welcome him back instead of only three as he would expect, he may also comment "这桌饭可真有排面啊。“ In this case it has nothing to do with grandeur or flamboyance, but only being more well-prepared that one would expect, and here it actually expresses gratefulness.

膨胀 literally means "to inflate". And just like in English, it also has a figurative meaning in Chinese: “我膨胀了” does not mean "I inflated", but rather "I was so flattered that I'm getting overly complacent."

When 花粥 said "排面" in this song, she is likely referring to the fact that her fans shouting "花粥带我回家“ in such a coordinated way made her feel too flattered. Here 排面 does not have any implication of fortune, social rank or luxury like the words "grandeur" and "flamboyance" do, but only means that the fans are shouting so passionately together and makes 花粥 feel that she's not quite worth that kind of passion. So it's more of the second kind of usage of this word that I mentioned.

Also, ”坦言搞得“ is not grammatical in Chinese.

Comment: Thanks! I have always had trouble distinguishing 'p' and 't' in recordings.